# openlayers interaction event unregisgistering

Tags: events, openlayers-3, interaction

I am trying to dynamically change interaction behaviour. It seems to have hit a wall with unregistering the events anyone that can help me with this?

This code:

```
map.un("click",ol.interaction.DragBox.handleDownEvent_,ol.interaction.DragBox);
```

gets a undefined error

Answer (score 2):

You cannot manipulate the internals of the library this way. What you can do is use setActive(false) on the interaction.

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.DragBox.html?unstable=true#setActive

Comment: thanks! seriously saved me hours of pain.... think im going to override it tho... setactive doesnt do exactly what i require. wish i could have used a library function without too much hassle. missing openlayers 2 XD